# Characterizing degree $n$ polynomials that are $n$-th powers in $GF(p)[t]$

Tags: polynomials

An old problem (recently  ``reheated" by Casas-Alvero, etc.) consists of trying to determine if  degree $n$ polynomials
$P(t)$ that are $n$-th powers
are characterized by the following condition:

$$
\deg( gcd(P(t),P^{(r)}(t))) >0
$$
for all positive integers $r$ and $r \neq n,$
where $P^{(r)}(t)$ is the $r$-th formal derivative of $P(t)$ relative to $t$.

Seems that the case when the field of coefficients is the prime field $GF(p)$ has not been considered.

By chance I got the following polynomial $P_{37}(t) \in GF(37)[t]$ that proves the (conjectural) result false:

$$
P_{37}(t) = 17t^{12}+21t^4+24t^3+12t^2 \in GF(37)[t]
$$

We have indeed:

$$
\deg(\gcd(P_{37}(t),P_{37}^{(r)}(t)) \geq 1
$$
in $GF(37)[t]$
for all $r=1,2, \ldots,11$ and trivially for $r>13.$
But,

$$
P_{37}(t)
$$
is not a $12$-th power in $GF(37)[t].$

More precisely:
$$
\gcd(P(t),P^{'}(t))=t, \quad \gcd(P(t),P^{''}(t)= t+36,
$$
$$
\gcd(P(t),P^{(3)}(t))=t+36,
\quad \gcd(P,P^{(4)}(t)=t+36,
$$
and all other $\gcd(P(t),P^{(r)}(t))=t$ for $r=5, \ldots,11$ and for $r>12.$

Question: There are other such examples ?. Can be characterized ?

Comment: (1) Casas-Alvarez should be replaced by Casas-Alvero. (2) ArXiv math 0605090, page 4, Section 3
has to do with Hasse derivatives, not true derivatives.


Comment: Corrected reference; added details of $\gcd$'s.

Comment: The degree 6 polynomial at the end of Section 3 in the reference you give is still a counterexample with true derivatives.

Comment: @dke: Right.!!!

Comment: The simplest similar example I can come up with by hand is $x^2(x+1)(x+3)\bmod 7$.

Comment: @dke: Great. Do you feel some "method" of construction may exists

Comment: @LuisHGallardo You say it is an old problem. Can you please name some references, or authors who worked on this, prior to Casas-Alvero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x^{p-1}-x^{(p-1)/2}$ for $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$.